# liquibase-hibernate5 not working with liquibase-maven-plugin

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot Starter 1.4.2.RELEASE + Hibernate 5 + Hibernate Spatial + Liquibase 3.5.3 + Liquibase Hibernate 5 (liquibase-hibernate5 3.6) + PostgreSQL and I can't make work the liquibase:diff goal.

Here is my setup:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>${postgresql.driver.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <diffExcludeObjects>geography_columns, geometry_columns, raster_columns,
                    raster_overviews, spatial_ref_sys</diffExcludeObjects>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</url>
                <!--<defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>-->
                <username>myusr</username>
                <password>mypwd</password>

                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:my.package.with.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</referenceUrl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <logging>debug</logging>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Running mvn clean compile liquibase:diff -X gives me the following exception:

```
.
.
.
[WARNING] HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
[WARNING] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
[INFO] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
[DEBUG] IdentifierCaseStrategy for both quoted and unquoted identifiers was set to the same strategy [MIXED]; that will likely lead to problems in schema update and validation if using quoted identifiers
[INFO] HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
[DEBUG] Adding type registration pg-uuid -> org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@2486d0ae
[DEBUG] Adding type registration java.util.UUID -> org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@2486d0ae
[INFO] HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@412e11bf
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.495 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-31T15:01:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 60M/616M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) on project my-application: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: The application must supply JDBC connections -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) on project my-application: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:398)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:127)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:166)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:955)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringPackageDatabase.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateSpringPackageDatabase.java:94)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database.buildMetadataFromPath(HibernateEjb3Database.java:51)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.buildMetadata(HibernateDatabase.java:136)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection(HibernateDatabase.java:75)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:131)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:85)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:83)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I really don't understand why this happens. I tried everything. I'm doing SQL calls from my RestControllers through JPA Repositories without any problems. I'm also able to run other liquibase maven goals without problems (successful connection to DB).

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: So I was able to do a workaround by removing `@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDate")` and `@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentZonedDateTime")` annotations from my ZonedDateTime objects in entities.

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to a working project you can share? I am trying to use hibernate-spatial as well, but liquibase:diff throws ```liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist```

Comment: Hi, Hervian, unfortunately I don't have my project anywhere. However, I had this problem before. Can you share liquibase and pom.xml configurations? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I discover that you can add property `-Djadira.usertype.useJdbc42Apis=false` to skip this error. See following code https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/blob/d55d0238395f0cb900531f1f08b4b2d87fa9a4f6/usertype.spi/src/main/java/org/jadira/usertype/spi/shared/AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java#L56

I think (not tested) you can set `systemProperties` in configuration.

```
<configuration>
  <systemProperties>
    <property>
      <name>jadira.usertype.useJdbc42Apis</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
  </systemProperties>
</configuration
```

Best Regards